# need query logic for different start and end datetime as results based on scedule run time

Tags: sql

i need the query logic like case or something to get required result set
for example if we take today i need the following results based on schedule run time

schedule timings 1:30 am UTC means(if i execute between 24th between 0130 hr to 13:29 hrs) the he following should be my result

start_date='2018-10-24 12:00:00' and end_date='2018-10-25 00:00:00'

schedule timings 1:30 pm UTC between (24th 1330 to 25th 0129 hrs)
start_date='2018-10-24 12:00:00' and end_date='2018-10-25 12:00:00'

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: need the logic to implement the sql query

Comment: this worked, let me know any flaws in it                                                                            select
CASE WHEN CONVERT( varchar(8),  GETDATE(),108) BETWEEN '01:30:00' AND '13:29:59' THEN
CONVERT( datetime, convert( date, getdate()))+'12:00' ELSE
CONVERT( datetime, convert( date, getdate()))+'12:00' END AS start_date,
case when CONVERT( varchar(8),  GETDATE(),108) BETWEEN '01:30:00' AND '13:29:59' then
CONVERT( datetime, convert( varchar(8), DATEADD(day,+1,getdate()), 112))  ELSE
 CONVERT( datetime, convert( date, DATEADD(day,+1,getdate())))+'12:00'   END as end_date

Comment: Great! Edit your question and cut and paste that comment into the question.

Answer (score 0):

select CASE WHEN CONVERT( varchar(8), GETDATE(),108) BETWEEN '01:30:00' AND '13:29:59' THEN CONVERT( datetime, convert( date, getdate()))+'12:00' ELSE CONVERT( datetime, convert( date, getdate()))+'12:00' END AS start_date, case when CONVERT( varchar(8), GETDATE(),108) BETWEEN '01:30:00' AND '13:29:59' then CONVERT( datetime, convert( varchar(8), DATEADD(day,+1,getdate()), 112)) ELSE CONVERT( datetime, convert( date, DATEADD(day,+1,getdate())))+'12:00' END as end_date

Comment: need to remove milliseconds completely result gives 2018-10-24 12:00:00:000 but i need  2018-10-24 12:00:00